# How to implement Video and video list using two Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview, android-videoview

I am creating an application for `HonyComb` in which I have to display videos and video list.
For this I have created two fragments,one for displaying video and other for videoList.When user clicks on video list then that video should start playing in `videoview` in other fragment.

I have created custom `expandablelist` for displaying videoList(AS my videos are categorized into group). I have to display video image, title and description for which I have created a layout with an `imageview` and two `textview`.I am able to display the video list. Now I am stuck at two points:

1. I am not able to play the video when I click on the video list. `onChildCLick()` is not getting invoked but `onTouch()` and `onGroupClick()` are able to get invoked.
2. I want to play the video in full screen when user taps on the `VideoView`. I don't know how to implement that.

Please help me..

1. fragment_layout.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal" > 
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       class="com.abs.qpr.VideoFragment" >
   </fragment>

   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/listFragment"
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="0.6"
       class="com.abs.qpr.VideoListFragment" > 
   </fragment> 
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. MyActivity .java

   ```
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MyActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity{

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
   }

   }
   ```
3. VideoFragment.java

   ```
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

   public class VideoFragment extends Fragment{
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   Log.d("VideoFragment", "On Create View");

   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my_video, container,  false);
   return view;

    }

     @Override
     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     } 

   public void playVideo() {

   VideoView myVideoView2=  (VideoView)getView().findViewById(R.id.my_tecnique_video);
   String temp="android.resource://" + getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" 
   + R.raw.back_circles;

   System.out.println(temp + ": " + getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" 
               + R.raw.back_circles);

       myVideoView2.setVideoURI(video);
       myVideoView2.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
       myVideoView2.requestFocus();
       myVideoView2.start();
    } 
   }
   ```
4. VideoListFragment.java

   ```
   public class VideoListFragment extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   Log.e("VideoFragment", "On Create View");
   View view = inflater.inflate(
           R.layout.activity_my_techniques_video_list, container, false);
   return view;
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   Log.e("VideoListFragment", "On Activity Created ");

   ExpandableListView expList = (ExpandableListView) getView()
           .findViewById(R.id.my_tech_video_listview);

   expList.setAdapter(new VideoExpandableListAdapter(getActivity()));

   expList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandablelistview,
               View view, int i, int j, long l) {

           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Log.d("Checking.....", "onGroupClick()");

           VideoFragment fragment = (VideoFragment) getFragmentManager()
                   .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
           if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
               fragment.playVideo();
           } else {

               Intent videointent = new Intent(getActivity()
                       .getApplicationContext(), VideoActivity.class);

               startActivity(videointent);

           }

           return false;
       }
   });
   }
   ```
5. VideoExpandableListAdapter.java

   ```
   public class VideoExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

   private Context myContext;
   ArrayList<VideoListVO> videoListVO;

   public VideoExpandableListAdapter(Context context) {
   myContext = context;        
   }

   @Override
   public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
   }

   @Override
   public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
       boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   if (convertView == null) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);

   }

   VideoListVO vlvo= videoListVO.get(groupPosition);
   VideoDetailsVO vdvo=vlvo.getVideoDetailList().get(childPosition);

   InputStream is = null;
   try {
       String imageName=vdvo.getImageName();
       imageName="images/"+imageName+".png";
     is = myContext.getResources().getAssets().open(imageName);
   } catch (IOException e) {
     Log.w("EL", e);
   }

   Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

   ImageView ib2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.video_image);
   ib2.setImageBitmap(image);

   TextView titleText=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title_text);
   titleText.setText(vdvo.getVideoTitle());

   TextView descriptionText=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_description);
   descriptionText.setText(vdvo.getVideoDescription());

   return convertView;
   }

   @Override
   public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return videoListVO.get(groupPosition).getVideoDetailList().size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int getGroupCount() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return videoListVO.size();
   }

   @Override
   public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
       View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   if (convertView == null) {
       LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
      }
   TextView tvGroupName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvgrpname);
   tvGroupName.setText(videoListVO.get(groupPosition).getVideoType());

   return convertView;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hasStableIds() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return true;
   }

   }
   ```

Comment: Can you please share your code so that we can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please extend VideoListFragment from ListFragment (Proper way), where you can directly setadapter, can listen to listitemclick events etc which will help to solve your issue.

For that you can go through [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/) tutorial.

Then for solving your second issue (full screen view when tapping) :

When user touches the video part twice (taps)(you can get this with the help of ontouchlistener and a timer to check whether consecutive touch happened), make a call to another activity where in the view part, design for full screen view. So when user clicks back, it will come back to the fragment activity.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response...I am using `ExpandableListView` in my videoList I can't extend `ListFragment`and there is no support to extend `ExpandableListFragment`.I will try your logic for videoview.

Comment: Can you see in my code to find why `onChildClickListener()` is not getting invoked

Comment: I dint find any issues with your code..Can you please try setOnItemClickListener instead??